# Slow query on table | WHERE x | ORDER by timestamp | DISTINCT a,b,c,d | TAKE 20 when table large

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We are experiencing a sudden performance drop with a query structured like this:

```
table(tablename)
| where MeasurementName in ('ActiveJobId')
    and MachineId == machineId
    and SourceTimestamp <= from
    and isnotnull( Value)
| order by SourceTimestamp desc
| distinct SourceTimestamp, MeasurementName, tostring(Value), SourceTimestampUtc
| take rows
```

`tablename, machineId, from, rows` are all query parameters. rows is typically "20". Value column is of type "dynamic"

The table contains 240 Million entries, with about 64,000 matching the WHERE criteria. The goal of the query is to get the last 20 UNIQUE, non-empty entries for a given machine and data point, starting after a specific date.

The query runs smooth in the Staging database system, but started to degrade in performance on the Dev system. Possibly because of increased data amount.

If we remove the distinct clause, or move it behind the TAKE clause, the query completes very fast. (<1s). The data contains about 5-10% duplicate entries.

To our understanding the query should be performed like this:

1. Prepare a filter for the source table, start at a specific datetime range
2. Order desc: walk backwards
3. Walk down the table and stop when you got 20 distinct rows

From the time it sometimes takes it looks almost as if ADX walks down the whole table, performs a distinct, and then only takes the topmost 20 rows.

The problem persists if we swap  | order and | distinct around.
The problem disappears if we move | distinct to the end of the query, but then we often receive 1-2 items less than required.

Is there a logical error we make, can this query be rewritten, or are there better options at hand?

Answer (score 1):

> *The goal of the query is to get the **last** 20 UNIQUE, non-empty entries for a given machine and data point, starting **after a specific date**.*

**This** part of the description doesn't match the filter in your query: `and SourceTimestamp <= from` - did you mean to use `>=` instead of `<=` ?

> Is there a logical error we make, can this query be rewritten, or are there better options at hand?

If you can't eliminate the duplicates upstream, you can consider setting a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) that performs the deduplication, then query the view directly instead of the raw data. Also see [Handle duplicate data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates)

Comment: Right. What I meant to say was "before a specific date".